# JavaScript Button link prevent scroll on click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have an Html link that I want to use as a button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link" title="Click to copy" ng-click="copyToClipboard(item, $event)">{{ "{" + item.campaignGuid + "}" }}</a>
```

The problem is that after clicking, the link is scrolled into the middle of the page like this:

**Before click**

[image]

**After click**

[image]

The clicked row has scrolled to the vertical center of the page.

I have tried `$event.preventDefault()` or `href = "#"` but nothing works so far. Any solutions?

Comment: did you try removing ng-click event attribute from <a>?

Comment: what do you mean with "event attribute"?

Comment: i mean remove ng-click, i think the issue is in that attribute

Comment: i mean try using this <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link" title="Click to copy" >{{ "{" + item.campaignGuid + "}" }}</a>

Comment: that's the angular click directive, I really need it

Comment: I know just to diagnose the issue remove it then i'll suggest another solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
$event.preventDefault()
```

use

```
$event.stopPropagation();
```

here is example:

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-link" title="Click to copy" ng-click="copyToClipboard(item, $event); $event.stopPropagation();">{{ "{" + item.campaignGuid + "}" }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just having an empty href attribute, so: `<a href> ... </a>`.

There's no need to have `javascript:void(0)` in there.